# Cannot resolve symbol 'WebView'. JavaFX WebView with Maven in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, xml, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

The thing is simple. I want to create a javafx project with WevView support.
Here are the steps i followed:

- Open intellij, create new project, select javafx on the left side, and also select maven on the right side, finish.
- I added a javafx web dependency in pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
    <version>16</version>
</dependency>
```

- In the configuration for running, i created an `Application` configuration with VM option this `--add-modules javafx.web` as from this [S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66789873/cannot-import-javafx-webview-in-maven-project)
- I run the Application and the prebuilt example runs perfectly
- Open the `.fxml` using Gluon SceneBuilder.
- Added WebView, gave it an id, saved it
- Access the element in Controller class but there is an error

Error:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'WebView'

My Main class

```java
package com.example.webbrowser;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

My Controller class:

```java
package com.example.webbrowser;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class HelloController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private WebView web;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }
}
```

My fxml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.WebView?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.webbrowser.HelloController">
   <children>
      <WebView fx:id="web" layoutX="225.0" layoutY="87.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

My pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebBrowser</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>WebBrowser</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.8.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>16</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>16</source>
                    <target>16</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.example.webbrowser/com.example.webbrowser.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

***What changes should i make to make the WebView work correctly??***

Comment: Try to add the line `requires javafx.web;` to your `module-info.java`.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov, Woops, thanks it worked out. Posting that as as answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the line `requires javafx.web;` to your `module-info.java`.